# Whats the best approach to get a whole month date?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a website which gets some data from database and generate some statistics with this data.

The idea is to allow the user to pick a month and then only query data from that month. So, if the user picks January, query for data > 01/01/2011 and < 31/01/2011.

I thought about generating the starting data from the month and then add one month and subtract a day so I get the last day of the given month but I don't think that's the best approach and also don't know how to generate a full date from a given month.

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you think that's not the best approach? what's wrong with very simple date operations?

Comment: @Stofke what for SQL is designed? for date calculations? he is asking how to get dates, not how to compare it.

Comment: @Stofke he is asking not how to query but how to get a range.

Comment: @Stofke so what? being a newbie he would like most nice looking solution, not most efficient one

Comment: @Stofke read his comment under pure mysql-based yet efficient solution written by Anri: he's really have no idea what he is looking for.

Comment: @Stofke data manipulations is ALWAYS an issue. Start learning, baby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL centric way:

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = 3 AND YEAR(`date`) = 2011
```

Substitute the month and year numbers from your selection.

PHP centric way:

```
$month    = 3;
$year     = 2011;
$firstDay = "$year-$month-1";
$lastDay  = "$year-$month-" . date('t', strtotime($firstDay));

$query = "SELECT * FROM `foo`
          WHERE `date` >= '$firstDay'
            AND `date` <= '$lastDay'";
```

Comment: Nice that's awesome! I didn't know that sentence in MySQL I've tried and it works very well :)

Comment: Can MySQL use an index on the date when you're searching by MONTH and YEAR like that?  Or will it resort to a table scan?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting records for the last month:

```
select `id` 
from `orders` 
where `created_at` > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  AND `created_at` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

and for the previous month:

```
select `id` 
from `orders` 
where `created_at` > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
  AND `created_at` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to avoid :)

Comment: @Antonio quite contrary, that's what you were actually looking for. you can substitute `CURDATE()` with any date in `2010-03-01` format representing desired month and the rest would be calculated by mysql, while select tiself would be done most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a lesson for you.

Most newbie programmers are looking for "the best", "most efficient" methods and stuff.
While they judge efficiency... by amount of the code! "Less code - more efficient!" - they think. And of course being wrong. Let's compare your "efficient" solution with "inefficient" one:

```
mysql> explain select * from Board where year(date) = 2011 and month(date) = 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Board | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 18113 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+

mysql> explain select * from Board where date > '2010-12-31' and date < '2011-02-01';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Board | range | date          | date | 9       | NULL |  325 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Notice `possible keys` and `rows` parameters.

in the latter case a database going to get exact rows you need, in the former - its going to pick every row in the table, applying a function on the date and compare it with a constant.

Same goes for the solution from the poor guy who deleted his GOOD answer after your ignorant comment:

```
mysql> explain select * from Board where `date` > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB('2011-01-15', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND `date` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY('2011-01-15'), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Board | range | date          | date | 9       | NULL |  325 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Nuff said.

Comment: Lessons are fine but bad manners really suck. Please, next time just be more polite. I'm noob, really noob at programming but I just want to learn. Nobody borns with knowledge, have this in mind.

Comment: @Antonio what's so impolite in my answer what made you feel so abused?

Comment: It may be something about cultural differences, I don't know and sorry if you really feel your comment wasn't impolite. Here, in Spain, to call someone Ignorant it's a little bit rude but I really appreciate your comment since it helped me a lot and, next time, I could check by myself the performance of a query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving your data as DateTimeStamp, simply add the condition to your query which would only return results from specific month of specific year. You could use LIKE clause for this.